# Can we add a "Reviewer stats" button to every queue?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

When viewing an item that has finished the Suggested Edits Review Queue, a button labeled "Reviewer stats" appears that lets you see how many times the reviewers approved, rejected, and improved in the queue. However, I noticed that this feature only exists in the Suggested Edits queue. To me, it never provided any especially useful information, but it is somewhat cool to see.

Can/should this feature be added to every review queue? If not, then why is this only a good idea for the Suggested Edits queue?

Comment: What would you even show for a queue like "First answers"?

Comment: @vr. The number of times each reviewer selected "Looks Good", the number of times they chose to edit, and the number of times they shared feedback. Or, if that's too much info, just the number of reviews they've completed.

Comment: @MichaelM. I think the previous commentator's point is that, for First Questions, First Answers and Late Answers, it only takes **one reviewer** to complete the review.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, but why would that affect a reviewer stats button? I'm not sure I understand your point.